# opencart - sort by price do not care about special prices

Tags: sorting, opencart

At the store , in a category page ,when i sort by price (for both low to high or high to low ) , 
it doesnt care about the special prices , it sorts the products according to base price , not the latest decreased price..

And this causes wrong sorting for the products with special prices , it places them among the other products according to their normal price..

I couldnt find any solution , even a correct working example.
I am using 1.5.3.1  but as far as I can see this is a problem of all versions.

I will be glad if you may suggest a solution for this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

My small suggestion can you please add this module in your opencart I think your problem will be resolve.

[http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3690&path=5&page=2](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3351&filter_search=special%20product%20shorting)

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3351&filter_search=special%20product%20shorting

and another way it's not possible to shorting in among with the huge number of category products in a pages so need to apply a conditional query for special products.

Thanks,
Brendon

Comment: this timecount module is not related with the sorting problem. even in their demo you can see the same sorting problem. the product with a special price 12.87 is listed under 177.5..  I think there must be an additional query placing the special price in place of the normal price before running sorting query.. may be an additional module..